# Cannot find the Telegram Account type

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, lua-telegram-bot

I'm maintaining a group on Telegram. There is one user who keeps joining and leaving the group, I'm not even sure this is an account or what it is. I can't even send any personal messages. I'm using below-mentioned code to see the new chat participant data.

```
if ($message['new_chat_participant']) {
}
```

Here is the link of a screenshot when I try to Personal Message this person:

[image]

Comment: This feels more like a question about the Telegram software than about the programming interface.

Comment: Actually, I want to interact with this anonymous user and delete the service message sent by Telegram "____ joined the group". Normally when a new user joins the group it has a value for new_chat_participant. When this anonymous user join the group it has no new_chat_participant value.

Comment: so you have a bot and it gets the service message as update?
did you try to just delete it?

Answer (score -1):

Like the client clearly says it's a deleted account... you can't send messages to it, because it basically doesn't exist (anymore). also they shouldn't join groups...
your question is here clearly out of place and we can't help you here, you should ask the Telegram Support (Telegram Settings > Ask a Question).

Comment: Okay As you said it seems like it is a deleted account. If it is deleted account then how this person can manage to join and leave the group again and again?

Comment: how do you even know that it's the same person/account every time? i don't think that...
and i don't know how it is possible, but maybe it's just a bug, so talk to the support.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time.

Comment: there maybe are spam bots which only have the goal to create an account, join a group and imediately delete the account, so they cannot be reported or so.

Comment: So Its completely a flaw in Telegram Application.